# System of ODEs Matrix Representation?!

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, computational-mathematics

### Task:

Consider the system of first-order ODES:
\begin{align*}
y_1' =&5y_2-y_1+y_3\\
y_2'=&3y_1-y_2+t^2\\
y_3'=&y_3-ty_2
\end{align*}

Write out the matrix-vector representation of this system

$y(t+h)\approx Fy(t)+g$

Clearly define the elements of $y'$, $y$, $F$ and $g$.

### Question:

How do I approach this? I know that I'm meant to rearrange it somehow. And how would I account for t's in the system?

I would post my working out, but I actually have no clue where to start. I was taught that the elements of F and g may be functions of t as well as h. So I'm guessing accounting for t's in the system would have something to do with g...

Comment: I think you will get better response if you just type the few words and maths from the image instead of giving the link only.

Comment: @Ben Yeah I think so too, only I'm new to this and don't exactly know how to input mathematic notation onto this... Perhaps someone could help? :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Hint:

For $h\ll 1$, $y'(t)\approx\frac{y(t+h)-y(t)}{h}$. Now, solve for $y(t+h)$ and insert the ODEs for $y'(t)$.

## Edit: Complete solution

We first write the ODEs in terms of matrices, with $y(t)=(y_1(t),y_2(t),y_3(t))^T$ and $y'(t)=(y_1'(t),y_2'(t),y_3'(t))^T$:
\begin{equation*}
y'(t)=\left(\begin{matrix}-1 & 5 & 1\\3 & -1 & 0\\0&-t&1\end{matrix}\right)y(t)+\left(\begin{matrix}0\\t^2\\0\end{matrix}\right)
\end{equation*}
Then we realize that we should give the answer in terms of $y(t+h)$, indicating that we should use the formula
\begin{equation*}
\frac{y(t+h)-y(t)}{h}\approx y'(t)
\end{equation*}
We solve this formula for $y(t+h)$, and insert $y'(t)$ from above:
\begin{align*}
y(t+h)&\approx y(t)+h y'(t)\\
&=\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\0&0&1\end{matrix}\right)y(t)+h\left(\begin{matrix}-1 & 5 & 1\\3 & -1 & 0\\0 & -t & 1\end{matrix}\right)y(t)+h\left(\begin{matrix}0\\t^2\\0\end{matrix}\right)
\end{align*}
Now, we bring these equations into the required form:
\begin{align*}
y(t+h)&\approx \underbrace{\left(\begin{matrix}1-h & 5h & h\\3h & 1-h & 0\\0 & -th & 1+h\end{matrix}\right)}_{F(t,h)}y(t)+\underbrace{\left(\begin{matrix}0\\ht^2\\0\end{matrix}\right)}_{g(t,h)}
\end{align*}

Comment: That's simply using Euler's Method though isn't it? I'm after solving it using matrices :/

Comment: Yes, it's Euler's Method. You can solve it using matrices. For this, note that with $y(t)=(y_1(t),y_2(t),y_3(t))^T$, $y'(t)=(y_1'(t),y_2'(t),y_3'(t))^T$:

$y'(t)=\left(\begin{matrix}-1 & 5 & 1\\3 & -1 & 0\\0&-t&1\end{matrix}\right)y(t)+\left(\begin{matrix}0\\t^2\\0\end{matrix}\right)$

Hint: Combine this solution with my original comment to get the complete solution...

Comment: So would I rearrange this y'(t) equation for y(t), then change it to y(t+h)? But why doesn't the F matrix (the 3 by 3 one) have any h's in it? 

Sorry if this doesn't make much sense, I'm trying to go off an example that was given in class but I'm not understanding it very well.

Comment: @user80922: I modified my original answer to show the full solution instead of a hint only.

Comment: Aha! I forgot that the identity matrix could be used like that! Thank you so much, I think I understand it a bit better now!

Comment: By any chance, say if I was given h and y(0); do you know how to write an matlab algorithm that solves for, say, y(1)? I've calculated it by hand (after a long, tedious process) but I need to provide an algorithm that doesn't use ode solvers on matlab. Any suggestions on how to go about with this? Would I have to use loops?